# Where should I go for advice on well defined programming problems that are too broad for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I appear to occasionally fall into the trap of asking what I feel are well defined programming problems, but that are subsequently closed as 'too broad'. Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611742/are-there-any-simple-minimal-persisted-queues-for-use-in-net
- [Under what circumstances will .NET processes and AppDomains share loaded assemblies in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288769/under-what-circumstances-will-net-processes-and-appdomains-share-loaded-assembl)

Is there a place for these types of question in the Stack Exchange family? And/or should I be 'refactoring' the questions into more specific questions?

Or perhaps I need to recalibrate my judgement on what Quesions to ask on Stack Overflow and which are more appropriate on Programmers Stack Exchange?

Comment: Full transparency: here is one of the review items: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8722655

Comment: @gunr2171 so.. can you tell why you voted like you did?

Comment: Here is the other review item: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8918235

Answer (score 3):

Well, your first question is a recommendation question, which doesn't go too well on SO and on most of the other SE sites. The question is too broad since you ask for a list of possible implementations. These type of list questions aren't quite useful and will take a loud of text to answer it properly.

As [rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene) commented: maybe [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) is an option, but make sure to consult their [help](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help) and [meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/) first.

Your second question is open (reopened actually) and has quite some votes, so it seems to be perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm one of the close voters of that first question and it is a recommendation question but that wouldn't fly on SR. A better chance is programmers but the same advice goes: ask on their meta first. The question seems to be about a persitable/durable queue and possible implementations. The other one is a wondering question. If an actual problem is added (maybe: *how can I reduce the memory foot print of all loaded apps*) that would make it attract less close votes.

Comment: @rene thanks. I've updated my answer since I see it isn't really a recommendation as you pointed out. I also added in the pointer to Programmers, with the disclaimer.

Comment: I see Q1 is a recommendation Q in the same vein as 'how can I store lists of things in C#'? I happen to have one extra requirement - that the list isn't in memory.

Comment: That question encourages a list of a dozen implementations or patterns.

Comment: OK so perhaps I should edit out the list? I put the list there to explain the options I'd already considered and why none of them were perfect - i.e. to pre-empt those discussions by providing some research findings up-front.

Comment: Instead of "Are there any simple/minimal persisted queues" (yes, a list of), you could make clear one specific situation (this goes wrong because of that).

Comment: OK. What's the procedure here - edit the existing Q (probably heavily), or start a new one?

Comment: I would edit this one. It is still the same question. It will get in the reopen queue. Show your progress ;)

Comment: @redcalx it is more of a whiteboard problem then a programming problem. If you went for the msmq option and ran into a problem and then tried the sql-service broker and ran into a new problem you could have used that as context and then ask for solution to what you encounter while indicating you are open for other implementations/designs.